# Segmentation fault in C txt file I/O

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault

Ok guys, the purpose of my program is to read from a text file called orginal.txt  containing names in the format:

```
Kyle Butler
Bob Jones
Nathan Moore
```

The program then takes these names one at a time and turns them into something like:

```
Kyle.Butler@emailaddress.com
```

This address is then stored line by line in a new text file called final.txt

problem is, i can't get it to work, it gives me a segmentation fault and does not even get to writing to final.txt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void write(char line[100]);

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("original.txt", "r+");

    char line[100];
    char mod[30]="@fakeemail.com\n";
    while (fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL){
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<100; ++i){
            if(line[i]==' '){
                line[i]='.';
            }
            if(line[i]=='\n'){
                line[i]='\0';
            }
            strcat(line, mod);
        }



        FILE *fp2;
        fp2 = fopen("final.txt", "a");

        if (fp2 != NULL){
            fputs(line, fp2);
            fclose(fp2);
        }

    }

    fclose(fp);





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the segfault happening? On this line? strcat(line, mod);

Comment: As an upgrade, you might want to consider whether you need to open and close the output file for every single write.

Comment: Did you define a function of your own called `write`? There's already a C library routine called `write`. You should probably choose a name that's a little more unique to our application. `write` is pretty general.

Comment: Always check the return value of fopen(). It's going to bite you sooner or later.

Comment: And always check the return value of fclose() as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056309/not-checking-closes-return-value-how-serious-really

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems with the code, but the segmentation fault is probably caused by this `for` loop:

```
for(i=0; i<100; ++i){
    if(line[i]==' '){
        line[i]='.';
    }
    if(line[i]=='\n'){
        line[i]='\0';
    }
    strcat(line, mod);
}
```

Every time through the loop you are concatenating `mod` to `line`. Since you iterate the loop `100` times with no other option to quit the loop, and `line` is only 100 characters long, very soon you will write past the 100th character of `line` into some other part of memory.

Comment: +1 Fairly sure that `strcat` is supposed to be outside the loop, which would address what this answer points out as well.

Comment: cheers, i remember seeing that and thinking it looked a bit out of place :)

Answer (score 0):

Suggested changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 100   /* Somehow parameterize "100" */

void write(char line[100]);

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("original.txt", "r+");
    if (!fp) {   /* Check for error */
      perror ("open failed");
      return 1;
    }
    char line[MAXLEN];
     /* You don't need hard-coded array length with a static string */
    char *mod="@fakeemail.com\n"; 
    while (fgets(line, MAXLEN, fp) != NULL){
        int i;
        /* You don't need to iterate through more characters than the string contains */
        for(i=0; i<strlen(line); ++i){
            if(line[i]==' '){
                line[i]='.';
            }
            if(line[i]=='\n'){
                line[i]='\0';
            }
        }
        /* Move this OUTSIDE of your for loop */
        strcat(line, mod);

        /* Append to the output file */
        FILE *fp2;
        fp2 = fopen("final.txt", "a");
        /* You're checking for error: good! */
        if (fp2 != NULL){
            fputs(line, fp2);
            fclose(fp2);
        }

    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You would really call `strlen()` in the conditional expression, as opposed to just walking the string with a local `char*` until the null-char is hit (and throwing out the 100-step for-loop in the process)? Or is this just the minimal-change you're targeting?

Answer (score -1):

As mbratch wrote you write beyond 100 chars in line array. Here's a working code:

```
void write(char line[100]);

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("original.txt", "r+");

    char line[100];
    char mod[30]="fakeemail.com\n";
    while (fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL){
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<100; ++i){
            if(line[i]==' '){
                line[i]='.';
            }
            if(line[i]=='\n'){
                line[i]='@'; strcat(line, mod);
                line[i+strlen(mod)]='\0';
            }
        }
        FILE *fp2;
        fp2 = fopen("final.txt", "a");

        if (fp2 != NULL){
            //fputs(line, fp2); printf("%s\n",line);
            fprintf(fp2,"%s\n",line);
            fclose(fp2);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```